# Can't make the scrollView to grow from bottom to top in android

Tags: android

I have a View that contains a scrollView. The scrollView contains a LinearLayout that contains a list of Buttons. But, most importantly I want the scrollView to grow from bottom to top. But I can't seem to make it work. (Very new to Android)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: button list aligns to top]

If I remove the scrollView, then the list of buttons is aligned to the bottom.

[image: what I want the scrollview to look like]